# Самый быстрый способ передачи данных через Bluetooth для IOS и Android с гарантированной доставкой пакета?

Tags: bluetooth, android-bluetooth

Подскажите пожалуйста какой профиль/режим Bluetooth выбрать чтобы организовать двухсторонний обмен с гарантированной доставкой пакета?

Есть некое устройство к которому нужно сделать Bluetooth интерфейс и связать со смартфоном.

Из того, что мне известно:
Low Energy - медленно.
RFComm - не поддерживается на IOS.

Comment: На какую пропускную способность Вы рассчитываете?

Comment: @EgorRandomize Рассчитываю на 1 МБит/сек, при этом варианты меньше и больше тоже интересны.